# How to include a controller concern in all the controllers in a namespace in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have an `admin` namespace defined in `config/routes.rb`, with multiple controllers defined in that namespace. For example `Admin::InvoicesController` and `Admin::ReportsController`.

Furthermore I have a concern defined in `/app/controllers/concerns/admin_concerns.rb`.

I want to include that concern in all the controllers in the `admin` namespace. Instead of adding `include AdminConcerns` to all controllers, is there a way to include this concern in all controllers in the `Admin` namespace at once?

Comment: Have you considered creating an `Admin::BaseController`, including the concern there, and then having all your controllers in the `Admin` namespace inherit from the `BaseController`?

Comment: Yes, I have considered that, but I already inherit from top level controllers, because most code is shared with those. The concern I want to include is relatively small compared to what I reuse from the top level controllers.

Comment: And could `Admin::BaseController` inherit from your "Top Level Controller" so that all your `Admin` controllers pick up the methods from there, too?

Comment: No, that's not going to work, because I have multiple controllers that each inherit from a different top level controller. So `Admin::ReportsController` inherits from top level `ReportsController`, `Admin::InvoicesController` from top level `InvoicesController`, etc.

Comment: `Admin` is a `Module`, so I thought that it somehow should be possible to include the concern in that module, passing it on to all controllers in it. But I don't see how.

Comment: So, this namespace is **implicit**: https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#implicit-namespace

By defining the namespace **explicitly**, it should be possible to alter the `Admin` module. I thought that adding `app/controllers/admin.rb` with this content would be picked up:

```ruby
module Admin
  ABC = 'abc'
end
```

But this does not make `ABC` available in the controllers in the `Admin` namespace. So apparently I'm still doing something wrong here.